# Processing Datatype list

Tags: sml

How can I get the data out of datatype list?

I have a simple code in SML:

```
datatype (''a, 'b) dict = 
     Nil
   | Dictionary of {key:''a, value:'b} list;

datatype 'dict list =
    nil
  | :: of 'dict * ('dict list);

val d = (Dictionary [{key="hello",value=[1,2]}]);
fun aux ((x::y):{key:''a, value:'b} list) = [x];
```

I want to get the key from the head of the list but I can't even separate it.

When I insert:

```
aux d;
```

I get the next error:

```
stdIn:2.1-2.6 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: {key:''Z, value:zY} list
  operand:         (string,int ?.list) dict
  in expression:
    aux d
```

How can I split the head of the list? And how can I get the key?

Comment: Please add the error text to the question body.

Answer (score 2):

SML seems to have some trouble interpreting your datatype definition in polymorphic function definitions. I suspect that the problem is that it can't infer a type for `Nil` in the definition. I recommend dropping that clause and using the datatype definition:

```
datatype (''a, 'b) dict = Dictionary of {key: ''a, value: 'b} list;
```

This way all dictionaries are instances of a `Dictionary` pattern. The basis case in function definitions would be the pattern `Dictionary([])` or `Dictionary(Nil)` if you need an empty dictionary basis.

You do need to include the `Dictionary` constructor in you function definitions. To extract the key from the first entry you can do the following:

```
fun aux (Dictionary(entries)) = #key(hd(entries));
```

This uses the `#` operator to extract the field labeled `key` from the head of the list of entries. You can also use more pattern matching like this:

```
fun aux (Dictionary({key = x, value = y}::entries)) = x;
```

In either case, with your sample data you get:

```
- aux d;
val it = "hello" : string
```

Comment: it won't compile.
i get the next error:

          tire.sml:16.5-16.50 Error: constructor and argument don't agree in pattern [tyco
n mismatch]
  constructor: {key:'a, value:'b} ?.list -> ('a,'b) dict
  argument:    {key:'Z, value:'Y} list
  in pattern:
    Dictionary ({key=x,value=y} :: _)

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
-

Comment: What implementation of SML? SML/NJ accepted the definition right off the bat.

Comment: @dinozour See if it works now. SML seems to have a hard time interpreting your datatype in polymorphic function definitions. The real mystery is why SML/NJ accepted the definition in my original answer (the second definition now) since when I played around with it some more it didn't accept other definitions (like the first definition in the revised answer) which intuitively should have been the same.

Comment: it seems like the fun. "hd" works sometimes and not always.
i have no idea why.

Comment: @dinozour Give examples of what you mean by "works sometimes and not always"

Comment: works at the first run. at the second i get : yyy.sml:10.27-10.61 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: {key:'Z, value:'Y} ?.list
  operand:         {key:'X, value:'W} ?.list
  in expression:
    Dictionary ({key=nkey,value=nval} :: nil)

Comment: @dinozour This isn't much to go on. What is the difference between your "first run" and your "second run"? What definitions are you currently using? Perhaps you can edit your question to reflect your current problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your first datatype, `(''a, 'b) dict`, is isomorphic to the built-in type `(''a, 'b) list option` (because of the extra `Nil`).

Your second datatype, `'dict list`, shadows the built-in type `'a list`. Notice that calling your type parameter *'dict* does not make it special. You should probably not name it after a concrete type, but rather name it *'a* or *'key* or such.

Functions and types that refer to the old `'a list` (such as your first type and the built-in functions) will produce one kind of lists and functions that rely on this new definition of `::` and `nil` will produce *another* kind of lists. This is extremely confusing - *don't* override built-in types, make new ones with unique type names and unique value constructor names.

Your type error comes from feeding a value of type `(string, int list) dict` to a function that expects a `{key:''a, value:'b} list` (of the new kind of list). Clearly, the value `Dictionary [{key="hello",value=[1,2]}]` is not such a list.

Here is a simple dictionary implementation that uses the built-in lists:

```
structure Dictionary =
struct
    type (''a, 'b) dict = (''a * 'b) list

    fun insert (key, value, []) = [(key, value)]
      | insert (key, value, (key2,value2)::rest) =
          if key = key2
          then (key,value)::rest
          else (key2,value2)::insert (key, value, rest)

    fun lookup (key, []) = NONE
      | lookup (key, (key2,value2)::rest) =
          if key = key2 
          then SOME value2
          else lookup (key, rest)
end
```

It does not use datatypes, and it does not abstract away the representation of the dictionary. If you want to improve on the representation, going from a list to a kind of tree, you would probably need to rely on order comparison (less than, greater than, equals) rather than strictly equality.